# ansible mysql configuration in one file for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, ansible

I'm trying to write a single page ansible script for mysql installation and setup a new user and create a empty DB. what I've tried so far -

`hosts` file

```
[mysql]
webapp ansible_ssh_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

`mysql.yml`  (The single file for all tasks/vars/handelers) (both hosts and mysql.yml in same directory) and I can login in remote system using ssh

```
---
- hosts: mysql
  vars:
    - system_packages:
          - build-essential
          - python-dev
          - python-pip
          - libmysqlclient-dev
          - mysql-server
          - python-mysqldb

    - root_password: root

  tasks:
    - name: Install MySQL
      apt: pkg={{ item }} state=installed update-cache=yes
      with_items: system_packages
      tags:
        - setup

    - name: Start MySQL service
      action: service name=mysql state=started enabled=yes 

    - name: Update mysql password for root account
      mysql_user: name=root host={{ item }} password={{root_password}}
      with_items:
            - 127.0.0.1   #In case of distributed system how should I place Ip addr of this system
            - localhost

    - name: create db 'mydb'
      action: mysql_db db=mydb state=present       

    - name: Creates database user 'eric' with password 'eric' for 'mydb' and grant all priveleges
      action: mysql_user state=present name=eric password=eric priv=mydb.*:ALL

  handlers:
    - name: start mysql
      service: name=mysql state=started
```

when I run this script I get this output(+error)

```
failed: [webapp] => (item=127.0.0.1) => {"failed": true, "item": "127.0.0.1"}
msg: unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or ~/.my.cnf has the credentials
```

Comment: This looks like a code dump with no information about the goal. A reader may not be able to determine "What are you trying to achieve?"  Please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to mysql server before you will set root password. To do this use the following:

```
- name: Set password for root user
  shell:
    mysqladmin password "{{ root_password }}" -u root
```

Comment: I would rather prefer a genuine ansible module than to shell out (see the answer below) . The `mysql_user` module is for changing password ;) and therefore seems cleaner

Answer (score 0):

After a default installation on ubuntu, you only can login to your mysql as root with password "root". So to change your password you will have to set your mysql login user to root (as you did in the next task)

```
- name: Update mysql password for root account
  mysql_user: 
    name=root host={{ item }} 
    password={{root_password}} 
    login_user=root 
    login_password="root"
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
```

There is also a ready-to-go solution in [ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/1)

Comment: edited, as i mentioned `login_password` is empty -> `login_password=""`

Comment: Well, everything looks fine except the following points:
1. your lines are too long: you might set every parameter in the next line indented (see my post)
2. for reuseability i would set up mysql as a role (http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html)
3. Ansible playbooks should be idempotent, yours would fail on the second execution (as the root password has changed). I would set a condition (e.g `when: initial_install`) on the `mysql password for root account` task and set it as `host_variable` for the machines you use this playbook with.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this task inside your task/main.yml

```
- name: Copy the root credentials as .my.cnf file
   template: src=root.cnf.j2 dest=~/.my.cnf mode=0600
```

and this will be your root.cnf.j2

```
[client]
user=root
password={{ root_password }}
```

What it will do is, to connect the mysql from the root user without password and perform these task. You can remove it after running all the task or leave it like this because it is under root and have tight permission.